# populate jquery autocomplete with data from a database

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, haml, jquery-autocomplete

I'm using [jQuery Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories) with categories, I've used the demo code which worked fine, now i'm trying to populate the drop down with data from my database. I've used this code within my view:

```
:javascript
  $(function() {
      var data = [
          - Datasheet.find(:all).each do |ds|
            { label: "#{ds.title}", category: "Data Sheets" },
          - Brochure.find(:all).each do |br|
            { label: "#{br.title}", category: "Brochures" },

        $( "#search" ).catcomplete({
          delay: 0,
          source: data
      });
  });
```

but I get the error `undefined local variable or method 'ds' for #<#<Class:0x00000005c95a18>:0x00000005c8d570>`

I'm not sure if it's because i'm mixing haml with javascript? is there another way around this? All I have in my view is a text field called search, which works with demo code.

Comment: which file are you writing this code in. Can you please show the complete code as in the scopes

Comment: this is in the haml view for the form it's referring to!

Comment: I guess you updated the question with demo code, please show the code that you are trying so that people can help

Comment: sorry, forgot i'd updated my code! I've changed it to what i'm currently working with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code inside a filter such as `:javascript` isn’t treated as Haml, it’s just s string that gets fed through the filter, so `-` and `=` don’t work as they do in the rest of Haml. You can use interpolation (i.e. `#{...}` blocks) though. In fact that’s what’s causing your error – in `"#{ds.title}"` Haml is trying to evaluate the `ds`, but not in the context of the block passed to `Datasheet.find`.

`#{}` blocks can span multiple lines, so you could change your code to something like this:

```
:javascript
  $(function() {
      var data = [
          #{
          (Datasheet.find(:all).map do |ds|
            "{ label: \"#{ds.title}\", category: \"Data Sheets\" }"
          end +
          Brochure.find(:all).map do |br|
            "{ label: \"#{br.title}\", category: \"Brochures\" }"
          end).join(',')
          }
      ];

      $( "#search" ).catcomplete({
        delay: 0,
        source: data
      });
  });
```

Here instead of using `each` to iterate over each array we use `map` to create a new one, then use `+` to add the two arrays together and finally use `join(',')` to combine them into a single string which is inserted into the page.

This is a pretty ugly and unwieldy bit of code however. A better solution in this case would be to extract out the code that creates the array into a helper and call the helper from your Haml.

Helpers:

```
def datasheet_array
  Datasheet.find(:all).map do |ds|
    "{ label: \"#{ds.title}\", category: \"Data Sheets\" }"
  end
end

def brochure_array
  Brochure.find(:all).map do |br|
    "{ label: \"#{br.title}\", category: \"Brochures\" }"
  end
end

def array_for_js
  "[#{(datasheet_array + brochure_array).join(',')}]"
end
```

Then your Haml can be the much clearer:

```
:javascript
  $(function() {
      var data = #{array_for_js};

      $( "#search" ).catcomplete({
        delay: 0,
        source: data
      });
  });
```